# Remote ftp server: Cannot open data connection

Tags: pantheon-terminal

As shown below, it seems that the connection is ok until I type ls. When that happens the system stays on 227 entering active mode for a few minutes and then I get code 425. Here it is:

```
    williepabon@WP-Pavilion:~$ ftp -4 192.168.0.4 1085
Connected to 192.168.0.4.
220 ESFtpServer 0.1 ready.
Name (192.168.0.4:williepabon): 
331 User name okay, need password.
Password:
230 User logged in, proceed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> pwd
257 "/" is current directory.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Active Mode.
425 Cannot open data connection.
```

I tried using gnome-terminal and the same thing happens. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with passive mode ("ftp -p")?

Comment: Ok. I've added the right answer to help others

Comment: The other solution I found was to open  port  1085 in my firewall. After doing that, ftp also worked fine. Thanks for  the help.

Comment: Fine, Williams. Added

Comment: Is Elementary straight forward, i can't connect FTP server on my phone

Answer (score 3):

You must use passive mode

```
ftp -p4 192.168.0.4
```

However,  you can also open port 1085 in your firewall.